# java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text could not be parsed at index 20

Tags: java, datetimeparseexception

**java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '2020-08-21T14:00:00.00+0700' could not be parsed at index 20** exception got for below code.

ZonedDateTime.parse(iso8601DateString, "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ")

it worked in java 11 but it got exception in Java 17.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend you use the following `DateTimeFormatter` which can serve for the varying number of digits in the *fraction-of-second*. It will also hold good when the *second-of-minute* (and hence the *fraction-of-second* too) part is absent.

```
DateTimeFormatter dtf = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
                        .append(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME)
                        .appendPattern("Z")
                        .toFormatter(Locale.ENGLISH);
```

Alternatively, you can use `DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSZ", Locale.ENGLISH)` but this is just specific to the given date-time string.

**Demo**:

```
class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String strDateTime = "2020-08-21T14:00:00.00+0700";

        // Recommended
        DateTimeFormatter dtf = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
                                .append(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME)
                                .appendPattern("Z")
                                .toFormatter(Locale.ENGLISH);
        OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.parse(strDateTime, dtf);
        System.out.println(odt);

        // Alternatively,
        dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSZ", Locale.ENGLISH);
        odt = OffsetDateTime.parse(strDateTime, dtf);
        System.out.println(odt);
    }
}
```

**Output**:

```
2020-08-21T14:00+07:00
2020-08-21T14:00+07:00
```

[<kbd>ONLINE DEMO</kbd>](https://ideone.com/FtWrVW)

Learn more about the modern Date-Time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

Answer (score 0):

Got it worked with 2020-08-21T14:00:00.000+0700, milliseconds should be three digit (000)